# Associate extra scalar data field with mesh or pointcloud

Tags: mesh, file-format, point-clouds

I work with scientific pointclouds and I often have extra columns of data in my .ply files. For example, I might have a column for "temperature" where there is a temperature value for each point or mesh triangle. In a 3D package called CloudCompare, it's easy to hide parts of a pointcloud or mesh based on the value of one of these "scalar fields."

Is there a similar feature in Blender? If I have a .ply with extra columns, is there any way for me to, say, color the mesh by the value of that column, or use that column as the input to a python script?

Comment: there is a vertex group option you can use it the same way it hold a value between 0.0 and 1.0 (on the point level )  and there is a special mode to display this value as a color on the mesh

Comment: Chebhou, I did not fully understand your comment, but I think maybe you have the right idea here. If I could import the extra column in the .ply as vertex group data, that would probably answer my question. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this format so how are you importing the file ?  is there an addon or a script i could alter it to get this option ?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that it was a plugin. [Here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Stanford_PLY) it is. PLY is very simple -- basically just a table of numbers, in ASCII or binary format.

Comment: I'll see if i can get it

Comment: @Chebhou the Stanford ply import/export addon is included with blender, just enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the import script so you can get extra info from the file as vertex weights with a factor as object property
ex : temperature info column will generate

- vertex_group named 'temperature'
- object property named 'temperature_factor'
- point temperature = vertex_weight*temperature_factor

download this file (  [import_ply.py](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35183)  ) and replace the one in `Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\scripts\addons\io_mesh_ply\` , restart blender after that to take effect

---

I have used the factor to normalize all values (0.0<->1.0) because weight can't handle more than that

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, above and beyond the call of duty! This is really useful!

Comment: @foobarbecue thanks, be sure to try and give feedback

Comment: think you can link the script again?

Comment: @Derek sorry i don't i think i have it now